# Apply theme customization on a financial app

Tags: gui-design, user-behavior, user-expectation, design-patterns, interface

I am designing a UI design for a financial app, can a user apply different themes to change between colors of the UI, so what themes are best suited for this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the thought presented is interesting my advice would be to take this thought up with a few potential users to understand whether do they even need such an application of changing UI color themes in 'FINANCIAL APP'?
In my opinion a clear alternative of DARK/LIGHT mode is enough as it will preserve the brand identity.

Answer (score 0):

Many apps provide both light and dark modes; if your financial app is using red or green numerals or indicators, you'll want to make sure there's [enough contrast](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/) for them to stay readable in either mode.

Consider branding -- does your app have distinct brand colors? Or do you aim for white-labeling or personalization, letting your customer choose some color elements? In either case, it's best to use bright or super-saturated brand colors sparingly and opt for neutral tones for most of the layout "furniture".